# How can I reset the source code of an Emacs package to its original state?

Tags: package

Suppose I have installed company-0.9.13, which other packages depend on (mostly third-party company completion backends). I unwisely edited company-mode's source code directly in the `~/.emacs.d/elpa/company-0.9.13/` directory. Now I want to undo all my edits and reset the source code to its original state. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you uninstall and then reinstall?

Comment: @Mark Is there no other way?